# How to run DB migrations that effect only on heroku fork app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, postgresql, heroku

On heroku I create fork app using `heroku fork --from sourceapp --to targetapp`

By this I copy an existing application and Heroku Postgres data.

Now I push some migrations on fork app using `git push forked master`.

How I run these migrations on heroku that it effect only heroku-fork app.

When I run `heroku run rake db:migrate` , is it effect both or only fork one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have multiple applications associated with the same codebase, Heroku will ask you which application you want to run the command on.

You'll specify that with the `-a` or `--app` flag, so for example

```
heroku run rake db:migrate --app <APPNAME>
```

This will allow you to run commands on the fork app or the source app.